# How to create a one-click preference entry in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a preference entry in android, but none of the possibilities mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) seem to satisfy my needs.

I want to create a simple clickable area, which I then want to use to reset some database entries in my app. I do not need a checkbox, a list or something like that. I am looking to create something like in the image found [here](http://false.ekta.is/2011/04/view-only-preferences-for-android/): I mean the "Unmount SD card" preference. How is this being created?

When the user presses on that entry some process is started in the background (after a confirm dialog...).

[image]

Comment: You could take a look at the Settings app source code and find out specifically what they do. My guess is that it is a plain `Preference`, with a listener attached to do the related work.

Comment: Good idea, I will try this...

Comment: But a `Preference` does not seem to have an id. How to refer to this then from the activity?

Comment: "But a Preference does not seem to have an id" -- preferences have keys, not IDs.

Comment: keys for persistent data storage, which is not what I want here. I want a press on the preference-item to start some action. A key is useless here...

Comment: A key is how you find the `Preference` from the `PreferenceGroup` or `PreferenceScreen` that holds it, [using `findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95800/discussion-between-alex-and-commonsware).